# How to convert a SDL window to a SDL surface? SDL 2

Tags: c++, software-engineering, sdl

I am trying to make a paint program and there is a sdl function called IMG_SavePNG() which requires a surface and destination file. How can I turn what I see in the window to a surface?

Comment: I haven't used SDL in a very long time however, since what your asking is equivalent to taking a screenshot, just get the backbuffers SDL Surface and pass it to your IMG_SavePNG();

Comment: @Grey Can you explain?

Comment: Answered your question. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You can use [SDL_GetWindowSurface()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) to get a surface from the window. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20233470/1212968

Comment: @Grey uh there is no answer?

Comment: Sorry I deleted it. I did something SDL 1.0 specific. Go ahead and try what Aidan Said and pass it to your function. Shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @AidanMueller has stated the answer to my problem

Comment: I am going to add an answer to this question so that we can lower the unanswered questions count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this in SDL, you need to use the [SDL_GetWindowSurface()](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface) funcion. This function will return the surface associated with the window. You can then pass the surface to the `IMG_SavePNG` function to take a screenshot.